# Converting string from .csv to datetime to tell if it is a specific week day

Tags: python, csv

I am reading in a csv file and printing it in list form by line so it prints like this:

```
['1555', 'A rotary phone', '6/25/16', '$186 ']
['1444', 'A top hat', '10/5/16', '$77 ']
['1666', 'A turtle', '9/28/16', '$198 ']
```

What code can i write to take the date from each line and determine whether that date for that entry is a friday using the datetime module? I am working on my skills and this would help a lot. thanks.

Comment: See also [**`calendar`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime`: ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime_obj = datetime.strptime('6/25/16', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> datetime_obj.weekday()
5
```

Function:

```
def is_friday(l):
    return datetime.strptime(l[2], '%m/%d/%y') == 5
```

Or even:

```
is_friday = lambda l: datetime.strptime(l[2], '%m/%d/%y') == 5

>>> is_friday(['1555', 'A rotary phone', '6/25/16', '$186 '])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date is always at position 2, you can use `datetime.strptime()` function to retrieve the weekday and see if it is friday.

```
from datetime import datetime
l = ['1555', 'A rotary phone', '6/25/16', '$186 ']
t = datetime.strptime(l[2], "%m/%d/%y")
t.weekday() # Will return 0 for Monday, 1 Tuesday and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use weekday() found in datetime ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)).

```
import datetime
#                          this string manipulation adds the '20' to make the date '2016'
datetime.datetime.strptime(lineOfCSV[2][:-2]+'20'+lineOfCSV[2][-2:], "%m/%d/%Y").date().weekday()
```

This will return an int which matches to a weekday:
0: Monday
1: Tuesday
2: Wednesday
3: Thursday
4: Friday
5: Saturday
6: Sunday